# Override properties set in JAR file with local properties

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a Spring 3.0 MVC project that uses a JAR file from a different project as a dependency. This JAR file has an "auth.properties" file in it's resource and has a string in it like this.

```
Ex: packages.redirectUrls.gotoUrl = 'http://myUrl.com';
```

Now, I am referring to this string in JAR File in my controller using:

```
@Value("${packages.redirectUrls.gotoUrl}")
```

I also have a local "auth.properties" file that consists of the same string with a different value in it.

```
Ex: packages.redirectUrls.gotoUrl = 'http://newUrl.com';
```

However, my Java code is not able to read this new configuration and always loads from the JAR File. Is there a way to override the JAR file setting with this new setting?

Thanks,

Comment: How do you load properties? Do you use `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`? Can't you solve your problem with just ordering files in your properties loader?